# "The specified module could not be found." when testing xna application on other machine

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, xna, filenotfoundexception

I get this error when trying to run my application in a Virtual Machine and every other machine, but not on the dev machine. The application keeps showing "Application has encounted a problem and needs to close." Find out more, I found that it encounted a "The specified module could not be found." exception.

Problem seems relating to main xna framework dll `Microsoft.Xna.Framework`, because the code is very simple:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Vector2 test = new Vector2(10,10); 
    }
}
```

(no more codes). These are what i've tried:

- Change Microsoft.Xna.Framework.dll reference's CopyLocal property to True
- Changing Solution Build Configuration: Debug <-> Release, and x86 <-> Any CPU. The app won't run with any configuration.
- Reinstall XNA game studio on dev machine and Repair XNA redistribution on testing virtual machine.
- Try to extract the Microsoft.Xna.Framework.dll inside the redist package outside and reference it

I'm running XNA 2.0 for compatibility (dll 2.0.11128.1). Both Virtual Machine and dev machine uses Windows XP with .net 2.0. I'm using Visual Studio 2010.